# Azure AD - Identity Experience Framework - Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I want to implement custom policy in the Identity Experience Framework to authenticate Azure AD users. I have successfully uploaded the XML files for local and Azure AD users.
When I run the sample application and try to log n using the Azure AD account, I got the following error.

Error message:

> AADB2C90240: The provided id_token is malformed and could not be parsed. Please provide another token and try again

so, someone can help to solve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes

Answer (score 0):

The error usually occurs if there is issue with the ID token as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes).

***I agree with Markus Meyer, to resolve the error try generating the token with symmetric keys.***

Create a **shared key** and add Azure AD B2C add the signing key like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure AD B2C -> Policies -> Identity Experience Framework -> Policy Keys -> Manual*

- Use **`IdTokenHintKey`** for Name and enter the sign-in key in the secret box.
- Use encryption for usage and create.
- Create a technical profile which validates the token.
- Create a policy

To know how to do it in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Define an ID token hint technical profile in a custom policy - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint#how-to-guide)